# uninitialized constant on class from ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, wrapper

I am trying to implement a gem called stanfordparser which can be found here: http://stanfordparser.rubyforge.org/

It is a ruby wrapper for a java natural language parser

I am developing in netbeans using ruby on rails / jruby on a windows 7 machine. My web app works fine otherwise, but when I try to add the parser wrapper it breaks.

Here is the code that is causing a problem:

```
gem 'stanfordparser'

def show
 parser = StanfordParser::LexicalizedParser.new
 @words = parser.apply("This is a sentence.")
end
```

this is in the taskscontroller

and when I go to tasks/show  (which, if i remove this code, works fine) I get the following error

```
uninitialized constant TasksController::StanfordParser
```

I have made sure the gem is installed in netbeans

I am very new to ruby on rails, and teaching myself, so it may be something obvious

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I checked my glassfish server logs and it says

```
SEVERE: Missing these required gems:
  stanfordparser
```

which is weird because I've installed the gem using netbeans, I've done rake gems:install and netbeans says the gem is installed. I've checked in netbeans gems folder and the gem is installed there.

**EDIT 2:**

So, after a lot of research and head banging, I've decided to simplify things a bit by just trying to use jruby to implement the java classes, now I need to figure out how to import the stanfordparser java classes (there are at least 50), I think I need to compress all the classes into a jar so that jruby can load it. maybe.

Comment: What does `rake gems` report?  (Is the gem installed, frozen, or something else?)

Comment: rake gems has nothing, so apparently no gems are being loaded


    I = Installed
    F = Frozen
    R = Framework (loaded before rails starts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem the following way:

instead of using the stanfordparser ruby wrapper (which implements java ruby bridge to connect the java stanford parser to pure ruby), I use jruby to just implement the java from the stanford parser.

the code that ended up working:

```
include Java
require 'C:\\Stanford-Parser\\Current\\stanford-parser.jar'
require 'rubygems'
include_class 'edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser'

lp = LexicalizedParser.new(args) #args is the arguments, not copied here
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails 3 then the `gem 'stanfordparser'` statement needs to be specified in Bundler's **Gemfile** within the project's root. Otherwise, for Rails 2.x you need a `config.gem 'stanfordparser'` statement within **config/environment.rb**.

Comment: thanks

I added 'stanfordparser' to config/environment.rb and I got the following error

    org.jruby.exceptions.MainExitException: aborted
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    com.sun.grizzly.jruby.RackGrizzlyAdapter.service(RackGrizzlyAdapter.java:289)

etc etc (it kept going for a while)

I looked at the glassfish server logs and it says SEVERE: Missing these required gems:
  stanfordparser 

ive run rake gems:install, and netbeans says that it is installed, so I don't know what the problem is